# What does こと mean?

Tags: nouns, nominalization, formal-nouns, particle-こと

Please don't laugh at me.

I am super new to Japanese and only really have google translate to help me. I can find a lot of stuff online but I can't find a solid meaning for こと, and Google translate tells me it means "about", but I'm not sold. Also if you have any suggestions on a better (free) translator, I'm all ears.

Comment: `if you have any suggestions on a better (free) translator,` --  I don't think we should trust automatic translators..

Comment: Context needed; こと has quite a few meanings/usages such as "thing", "about", "concept", "experience", functions as a nominalizer, represents necessity, plan, routine, decision, period of time, exclamation, etc.

Comment: As you mentioned that you only have Google translate to help you, I would suggest you check out some online dictionary like https://jisho.org/ When it comes to meaning of a single word, dictionary is always better than Google translate, especially on words that have a lot of meanings and Google translate can only show you one.

Answer (score 4):

こと can refer to many things, including:

1. *koto* ([this Japanese musical instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koto_(instrument)))
2. to make up a cover story; glossing over
3. ancient capital; old city
4. difference
5. (sound) click; tick; knock
6. word; phrase
7. thing; matter
8. affair; incident; event
9. fact
10. situation; circumstances
11. problem; trouble
12. regarding ...; about ...
13. fact that ... (used to nominalize a clause)
14. also known as; alias
15. oh; what a; how (e.g. how wonderful..., what a big ...)
16. Do ...! (used to make an order)
17. Is it ...?; Do you ...?; etc (used as a question marker)

Please don't be overwhelmed. Japanese tends to have many homophones, and fundamental words are always like this in many languages. For example English word [`for` has 25 definitions according to a free online English-Japanese dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/for/#ej-33042). Unsurprisingly, Google Translate is useless for a word-by-word translation of fundamental words.

Asking for study methods is off-topic on the main site. But if you want to study Japanese seriously, please see: [Resources for learning Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese)